# Making a Berachah on rabbinically prohibited foods

Tags: halacha, blessing, kashrut-kosher, sin, derabanan

Should one refrain from making a Berachah on rabbinically prohibited foods, or does that rule only apply to biblically prohibited foods?

Comment: Can you cite where the rule is applied to biblically prohibited foods?

Comment: Not until I can get to a PC. #aboveaverageintelligencebutnotquiteageniusphone

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17535/759 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14905/759

Comment: Also related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/35861

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> אכל דבר איסור, אף על פי שאינו אסור אלא מדרבנן, אין מזמנין עליו ואין מברכין עליו לא בתחלה ולא בסוף. (שולחן ערוך או"ח סימן קצו:א)‏
>   If one ate something prohibited, even if it was only prohibited rabbinically, one does not combine him to a zimmun, nor would he say a beginning or after blessing [on that food]. (Shulchan Aruch OC 196:1)