# Making a bracha on kosher ingredients cooked in non-kosher pots?

Tags: halacha, blessing, food, kashrut-kosher, cooking-bishul

Is it assur to make a bracha on foods whose ingredients are kosher but cooked in non-kosher utensils? What is the source?

Comment: Are you asking if the resultant food is kosher, or are you asking if you can say a bracha on non-kosher food?

Comment: Was the pot clean and unused for 24 hours?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17534/759

Answer (score 2):

The Shulchan Aruch writes (196:1):

> אכל דבר איסור אף על פי שאינו אסור אלא מדרבנן אין מזמנין עליו ואין מברכין עליו לא בתחלה ולא בסוף׃
>
> If one ate something prohibited, even though it's only prohibited Rabinically, we do not form a zimum on it, and we do not say a beracha before or after eating it.

The key thing to note is that it is not necessarily a food's "kosher" status that governs whether a bracha is said. Rather, the key is whether it is permitted or forbidden to be consumed.

So in the case of food cooked in non-kosher utensils: it would appear (according to my understanding) that if the circumstances are such that it's forbidden to be eaten, one cannot make a bracha on it.

I should note that I have seen in the Aruch Hashulchan that there are certain exceptions to this rule when it comes to "lighter" Rabbinical prohibitions. An example he gives is בישול עכו״ם. I am not quite sure if this would have any bearing on the utensil case...

Comment: I don't see how you derive your "key note" from that statement in Shulchan Aruch

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm assuming that איסור is being used literally. This can be further seen by the Mishna Berurah there and by some of the other examples given by the Meforshim (e.g. נדר, stolen)

Answer (score -1):

If the utensils were not used within 24 hours, then bedieved even miderabonon the food is כשר. (Remember this is only bedieved where if it was an accident or a bshat hatchak). Therefore since it's כשר you can make a berachah.

Comment: As I and others have commented on your other answers, a source will increase the answer's value. Almost no one online knows who you are, so almost no one online has any reason to trust what you say unless you cite a source.