# What is the difference between kosher and permitted food?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, hechsher-certification

I wish to allude to [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/35864/1516) answer, which distinguishes between "kosher" and "permitted" (and "non-kosher" and "forbidden") foods for purposes of knowing when to make a bracha.

Can someone explain this distinction to me? What is a "forbidden" food? Are there foods that are "permitted" but not kosher/not kosher-certified?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10616/animals-vs-plants-kashrus#comment15334_10616

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That answer has follow-up comments discussing exactly your question. The answerer is assuming that the Halachah under discussion (not to recite a Berachah on "forbidden" foods) is worded carefully by the Shulhan 'Aruch and relates not only to foods that have an inherent Kashruth problem, but also to foods that a person has forbidden to himself or someone else has made forbidden to him - ie., through a vow.  It is not that the food itself is "unkosher"; but it is still forbidden for the person to eat it.

{It is worth noting that the plain reading of the Halachah is that the Shulhan 'Aruch was discussing "unkosher" foods, and was emphasizing their "forbiddenness" as relates to the *level* of the prohibition - Torah vs. Rabbinic - not the *nature* of the prohibition.  This seems to be @DoubleAA's main objection, but he is free to comment here to correct me.}

Comment: Thanks. I assume there are no "permitted" foods that are not in fact kosher?

Comment: Other possible examples of foods that are kosher but not permitted: chametz during Pesach; kosher dairy within x hours of eating meat; foods that one's community has a minhag not to eat at certain times (or meat when one has a minhag to eat dairy, etc.)