# A bracha on a tallit gadol and not kosher T"Katan

Tags: blessing, halacha-theory, tallit-gadol, kavana-concentration, tallit-katan

Does partially intentionally wrong kavanah make a bracha a bracha levatalah?

If I put on my tzitzit and notice that a string is missing (or something else which would invalidate it as proper tzitzit) and wear it any, and then later, when I put my tallit gadol on, have in mind that the bracha should cover my tallit katan as well (as per the M"B's [statement](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.8.24?ven=Sefaria_Community_Translation&vhe=Wikitext&lang=en&with=all&lang2=en) "And this is the custom nowadays, to make the blessing on the טלית גדול and have in mind to exempt with it the טלית קטן.") does the fact that I know that my bracha is intended to apply to something which cannot be covered by that bracha undermine the value of the entire bracha or is it still a valid bracha because I also have in mind the tallit gadol which is kosher?

Clearly, I'm not asking for a psak with the intention of doing anything like this but I want to understand the power of kavanah in determining the efficacy of a bracha.

Comment: It's forbidden for a man to keep wearing a four cornered garment without valid tzitzit on it

Comment: But isn't that a separate infraction? I'm asking about the nature of a bracha made with intentionally invalid intent. That the underlying behavior is also a problem is (to my understanding) a distinct violation.

Comment: Can't we make a simpler case then: a man says a blessing on his tallis and intends to also exempt with it his cat's shoes even though he knows they don't have tzitzit on them, don't have four corners, and that cats are exempt.

Comment: sure, but I was taking something that is explicitly listed as being able to be included by that particular bracha were it kosher

Comment: Cats shoes could also be included if they were being worn by a Jew with kosher tzitzit.

Comment: then I have no idea what "cat shoes" are that a Jew with kosher tzitzit would make a bracha when he puts them on.

Comment: If a partially wrong kavanna would be a problem, then every time there’s a sofek bracha, where one makes the bracha on something that is definitely chayiv, and includes in it the sofek, there should be a problem of possibly ruining the kavanna on the tzad that it is not chayiv

Comment: @Chatzkel yes and I'd love an answer to that as well, but in my case, there is no safeik -- the speaker knows that the T"K is not kosher and CAN'T be included.

Comment: This question would be relevant if someone moved into a new home and affixes mezuzos on every doorway, even those that are not required according to all shitos. He makes one bracha and has in mind for every doorway. I’ve never seen anyone say that it’s an issue

Comment: Or having in mind to check a room that is definitely pattur from bedikas chometz when you make the bracha on the bedika. Never heard anyone mention it to be an issue

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/82845/is-saying-a-bracha-over-non-kosher-food-a-sin-or-does-it-simply-not-count-as-a-m/82850#82850 and https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/115107/should-one-recite-a-bracha-for-non-kosher-meals/115116#115116

Comment: @ chatzkel there's a difference between pattur and assur. A 4-cornered garment without kosher tzittzit is assur.

Comment: I thought the bracha was on the biur

Comment: That's very interesting, @rosends. Where do you think you got that idea?

Comment: There might be an issue of bal tosif if he has intention to make something that isn’t a mitzvah into a mitzvah. Just a thought