# Bentching after accidentally eating prohibited foods

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, mistakes, bentching, intent-accident-purposely

Should one recite Birkath HaMazon after eating foods that one did not realize were prohibited, or does this fall under the idea that doing so is offensive?

Comment: Citing not bentching after purposely eating them would add context to your question and better it.

Comment: No doubt. See my comment on the other question I just posted of a similar nature.

Comment: Huh? Why would it be offensive?

Comment: @AdamMosheh Tehillim 10:3

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14905/759

Comment: I asked this once to a Talmid Hacham and he responded not to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Taz (OC 196 sk 1) rules that one who ate something prohibited (even Biblically) by accident is allowed to say an after bracha, as it is no worse than one who eats prohibited foods when forced to because of pikuach nefesh which the Shulchan Aruch already rules (OC 196:2) do get blessings.

The Mishna Berurah (sk 4) quotes this Taz approvingly, but the Aruch HaShulchan (:4) questions him and seems to disagree. CYLOR!

Comment: I think that there is a machloket between RAhA and someone else in Brachot but I have no books to verify