# Eating treif b'shogeg

Tags: kashrut-kosher, bentching, intent-accident-purposely, ikar-tofel, taarovet

If I ate a hamburger that I thought was kosher and after I finished it I found out it was not kosher, where does that leave me halachikly speaking. I know in Mishnah Torah it says (Blessings 1:19)

> Whoever eats forbidden food, wilfully or in error—recites no blessing
>   either before or after.

What if I said Hamotzi before the meal? Assuming the bread was kosher, was the bread the Ikar of the meal and do I still say Birkat Hamazon? Or does the unkosher burger meat still prevent me from it?

Comment: Which question is the ikar, here?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501). Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: The specific question is..does the treif meat completely remove me from the ability to say Birkat Hamazon, even if I made motzi on the bread (i.e bun)?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17535/bentching-after-accidentally-eating-prohibited-foods

Comment: @Alex Doesn't it qualify for a duplicate?

Comment: Why do you think this halacha changes bc you were wrong about the food being kosher?

Answer (score 1):

Based on Hilchos Bkias HaPat and down through Hilchos Birkas Hamazon, it would seem that if you ate a shiyur of bread which warrants Birkas Hamazon (a kezayis), then you could definitely say birkas hamazon on that bread (why not? you're blessing kosher food!).

However, if you rely on the halachic opinions that the other parts of a food object are "mashlim" the required shiyur--without which you don't have a shiyur for bentching--then it would seem you would NOT say birkas hamazon, since we don't make a blessing on something assur (I believe the latter is mentioned at the end of the above-mentioned halachos).