# Should a bracha be made on stolen food?

Tags: halacha, blessing, food, gezel-stealing

I already know that it is forbidden to make a bracha on a stolen lulav ([SA OC 649:1](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayyim.649)). However, i'm not sure if this also applies to making a bracha on stolen food. The difference seems to be that by a lulav, the bracha is on the *mitzvah*, which is being done with something forbidden. By food, the bracha is on your *benefit* (ברכת הנהנין), so it's possible that you might make a bracha on benefiting, even if it came to you in a non-permissible way.

So: should a bracha be made on stolen food?

Comment: בוצע ברך ניאץ השם

Comment: I knew some yeshiva boys who would always bring cookies with them when they broke into the kitchen, so they would have something to make a _bracha_ on before they ate the cake (that was locked in the kitchen).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Mishna Berurah (196:4)](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%A6%D7%95) says that if someone steals wheat, grinds it and bakes it, it is actually a Machlokes on whether he could say a Bracha on it. Nonetheless, from the Mishna Berurah it's clear that the Machlokes applies because in this particular case, the thief effected a change (שינוי) through which he acquires the item. However in a "standard" case of stealing it would appear that everyone agrees it's prohibited to say a Bracha.

[The Laws of Brachos](http://www.artscroll.com/Books/9780899062204.html) (page 144) indeed says:

> One who steals food, or even takes food without the owner's permission (or without being certain that the owner approves), may not recite a b'racha.

However, he does bring the above opinion from the Mishna Berurah in the footnotes  ("... some authorities require that a b'racha be recited").

Answer (score 5):

**No** -- a bracha should not be made on stolen food.

The gemara in [Sanhedrin 6b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=24&daf=6b&format=pdf) paskens that if someone would steal wheat, grind it, and bake bread out of it, a bracha still would not be made on that bread.

The Rambam ([Hilchot Brachot 1:19](http://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah,_Blessings.1.19)) brings this as the halacha -- any food that is *asur* does not get a bracha either before or after.

(Credit to [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/14906/5151) for pointing me to the gemara source, which pointed to Rambam.)

Comment: Why is stolen food _asur_?