# Giving maaser on bad money

Tags: maaser-tithes

If someone takes money that doesn’t belong to him, is he still obligated to give maaser on this stolen money?

Comment: this would be a mitzvah ha'ba b'aveira. i would recommend editing the question for clarity: whether you're talking bedieved or l'chatchila

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should a bracha be made on stolen food?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/50343/should-a-bracha-be-made-on-stolen-food)

Comment: Unsure what you're asking: The correct thing to do is to return the money (and possibly the 25% or 100% fine as decreed in the Torah.)

Comment: @DannySchoemann or 300% or 400% or [125% or 50%](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Terumot.6.4)